# Equally distribute text among a given amount of lines; automatically adjusting the width

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, paragraphs

Given some text, I want to centrally align this text on a given amount of lines.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna. 
\end{document}
```

gives [image]
However, I would like to advise LaTeX to distributed this text among 12 lines, whereby all lines (including the last one) have roughly the same width. Additionally, the output should be centered.

Comment: Is the number of lines known as a fixed amount in advance or is it in some way dynamic?

Comment: @JosephWright The number of lines is fixed and known in advance.

Comment: This is somewhat related to this question (regarding last line extending to right margin): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230840/artificially-improving-default-tex-algo-results-for-balancing-interword-spacing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{\indent Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna.}
\begin{center}
\dimen0=\dimexpr\wd0/12\relax
\loop
\sbox2{\parbox[b]{\dimen0}{\parfillskip=0pt plus .1\hsize\unhcopy0}}
\ifdim\ht2>12\baselineskip
\advance\dimen0 1em
\repeat
\usebox2
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If you change to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna.}
\begin{center}
\dimen0=\dimexpr\wd0/12\relax
\loop
\sbox2{\parbox[b]{\dimen0}{\centering\parfillskip=0pt \unhcopy0}}
\ifdim\ht2>12\baselineskip
\advance\dimen0 .5em
\repeat
\usebox2
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Then you get

[image]

Comment: lines don't have the same with

Comment: @touhami you mean the last line? I gave a bit of flexibility there, delete `plus .1\hsize` if that is not wanted.

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear. Is it possible to not only center the box, but also the individual lines? Further, how can I get rid of the indentation on the first line?

Comment: Very nice.  The use of iteration to achieve the text-fit reminds me of the related problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/making-the-text-fit-in-a-specific-space-in-latex

Comment: @Florian  Just add `\centering` before `\parfillskip`.

Comment: @Florian sure just add \centering inside the \parbox, it depends a bit whether you want to allow the last line to be short and whether you want indentation (ypur image in teh question showed an indent so I kept it)

Comment: @Florian see update

Comment: @Florian I went to some effort to manually add the indentation in the original version:-) note the explicit `\indent` in the `\sbox` :-)